# NPM fails to update Node on Windows 10

Tags: node.js, windows-10, npm-install

I am actually having trouble installing packages on my machine (Windows 10 Pro) but in the meantime that I am reading various pages on Stackoverflow and Github to resolve the issue, I tried updating Node and NPM with no luck. So if someone knows what is wrong here to do with this, might also help me understand the original problem I had.

In the attached snapshot, you see the current version of Node on my machine is 12.13.0, and when I update it with NPM, it should be 13.1.0 whereas running "node --version" still shows the old version.

I generally have problem with installing any new package on my machine. The user I am logged in with is an Administrator and I have access to anywhere on my machine. I have even tried running these commands in an CMD run as Administrator with no luck. Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

```
C:\>node --version
v12.13.0

C:\>npm install node -g

> node@13.1.0 preinstall C:\Users\***\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\node
> node installArchSpecificPackage

+ node-win-x64@13.1.0
added 1 package and audited 1 package in 2.671s
C:\Users\***\AppData\Roaming\npm\node -> C:\Users\***\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\node\bin\node
+ node@13.1.0
removed 1 package and updated 1 package in 6.004s

C:\>node --version
v12.13.0
```

Comment: err, curious question, why didnt you use the [nodejs installer instead](https://nodejs.org/en/)? personally i always use the installer whenever possible. oh right, have you checked in nodejs PATH? it may still point to the installation folder instead of your `C:\Users\***\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\node\bin\node`.

Comment: I did and it still does not work. I am now on version 13 but if I install anything, although the installation goes well, cannot run the installed package from the command prompt, either right after or with closing/re-opening the command window.